# Historic statistics

Tags: baseball, trivia, statistics, mlb

I've noticed baseball announcers, during an at-bat, using information on lifetime at-bats for the specific batter-pitcher combination.  Have these statistics been extended into the past, to answer questions like:

"What pitcher gave up the most home-runs to Babe Ruth?"

and

"What pitcher-batter combination produced the most life-time home-runs?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! Though you may not be able to get a lot of what you want for free.

Basically all of the box score information that we have is in the public domain So it's all available for free from [retrosheet](http://retrosheet.org/).

However, that's not a very usable format. Thus several services (including the ones that MLB and it's announcers use, Stats Inc) are available for you to peruse. However, this is expensive data to maintain and format, so you'll probably need a subscription to use it.

[Baseball Reference](http://www.baseball-reference.com/) is perhaps the most comprehensive publicly available store of baseball records (and can definitely do the kinds of queries your curious about). They will offer a limited amount of data for free, and all of the results of your queries if you're a subscriber. If you have an actual need for this, it's quite affordable.

Comment: It still sort of surprises me that someone hasn't made a public API to retrosheet, considering that their format, while not exceptionally human-friendly, would be *very* machine-friendly; I expect most of it is pretty scrapeable. I think I looked into it myself when I was reading http://plunkbiggio.blogspot.com/ .

Comment: I actually *started* at one point, but to do it from RS's stuff it requires a good bit of time and effort that I don't have right this second

Comment: Worth mentioning about Retrosheet is that it only has *historic* data and does not contain current year information.